# Someone help me on ajax in Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, jsp

```
I have a login.jsp contain: 2 text box username and password:

    <h1 id="loginID">Login required</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="username"><br> <br /> <input
            type="password" name="password" required> <br> <br>
        <input type="submit" onclick="loginEvent()" value="login">
    </form>

, and an javaScript file called loginAjax.js:
```

// my loginAjax.jsp located in WEB-INF/resources/pages/loginAjax.jsp
// my spring-mvc-servlet.xml :

```
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null)
}
and a file JSP loginAjax.jsp to access database :
```

// when running in browser ajax does not work!

```
and in console of Browser :
error: GET http://localhost:8899/SpringMVCHibernateTransaction/%3Cc:url%20value= 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: so can you direct me on calling request from Ajax to controller in spring? ex: I thinks that: I will create @RequestMapping("/user") in my Controller, and ajax'll call    $.ajax({
  url:'user.jsp',// I thinks this will mapp to //@RequestMapping("/user") 
  data:({name:'luong'}),
  success:function(data){
   $("#user").html(data);
  }
 });

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is client-side technique to create asynchronous Web applications. Here the error is 404. So, Ajax does it work. But there is no corresponding resource in the Server.